# Hallar area y perimetro de un triangulo

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas con este problema de encapsulamiento, especialmente en el resultado. Agradecería mucho la ayuda ofrecida. El código q tengo es este:

```
    private double puntoAx;
    private double puntoAy;
    private double puntoBx;
    private double puntoBy;
    private double puntoCx;
    private double puntoCy;
    private double ladoA_B;
    private double ladoB_C;
    private double ladoC_A;
    private double perimetro;
    private double area;



    //Constructor para los vértices del triángulo

    public Triangulo(double puntoAx, double puntoAy, double puntoBx, double puntoBy, double puntoCx, double puntoCy) {

        this.puntoAx = puntoAx;
        this.puntoAy = puntoAy;
        this.puntoBx = puntoBx;
        this.puntoBy = puntoBy;
        this.puntoCx = puntoCx;
        this.puntoCy = puntoCy;
    }


    //Método para hallar perimetro



    public double getPerimetro() {
        ladoA_B=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((puntoBx-(puntoAx)), 2))+(Math.pow((puntoBy-(puntoAy)), 2));
        ladoB_C=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((puntoCx-(puntoBx)), 2))+(Math.pow((puntoCy-(puntoBy)),2));
        ladoC_A=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((puntoAx-(puntoCx)), 2))+(Math.pow((puntoAy-(puntoCy)), 2));

        perimetro = ladoA_B+ladoB_C+ladoC_A;
        return perimetro;
    }


    //Método para hallar el área

    public double getArea() {
        double p = getPerimetro()/3;
        area=Math.sqrt(p*(p-(ladoA_B))*(p-(ladoB_C))*(p-(ladoC_A)));
        return area;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangulo:\nPunto Ax: " + puntoAx + "\nPuntoAy: " + puntoAy + "\nPuntoBx: " + puntoBx + "\nPuntoBy: "
                + puntoBy + "\nPuntoCx: " + puntoCx + "\nPuntoCy: " + puntoCy + "\nLadoA_B: " + ladoA_B + "\nLadoB_C: "
                + ladoB_C + "\nLadoC_A: " + ladoC_A + "\nPerimetro: " + perimetro + "\nÄrea: " + area;
    }


}
```

> ***************clase principal********************

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaTriangulo {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    double xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC;
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.println("Ingrese vértice A: ");
    System.out.print("Eje x: ");
    xA=stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Eje y: ");
    yA=stdIn.nextDouble();


    System.out.println("Ingrese vértice B: ");

    System.out.print("Eje x: ");
    xB=stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Eje y: ");
    yB=stdIn.nextDouble();


    System.out.println("Ingrese vértice C: ");

    System.out.print("Eje x: ");
    xC=stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Eje y: ");
    yC=stdIn.nextDouble();

    Triangulo trika = new Triangulo(xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC);

    trika.getPerimetro();
    trika.getArea();

    System.out.println(trika);
}

}
```

> ///y el resultado que me da es:

```
Ingrese vértice A: 
Eje x: 3
Eje y: -2
Ingrese vértice B: 
Eje x: -3
Eje y: 0
Ingrese vértice C: 
Eje x: 1
Eje y: 3
Triangulo:
Punto Ax: 3.0
PuntoAy: -2.0
PuntoBx: -3.0
PuntoBy: 0.0
PuntoCx: 1.0
PuntoCy: 3.0
LadoA_B: 10.0
LadoB_C: 13.0
LadoC_A: 27.0
Perimetro: 50.0
Ärea: NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

> p*(p-(ladoA_B))*(p-(ladoB_C))*(p-(ladoC_A)) debe de ser un número negativo. Tendrias que hacer el valor absoluto de ese termino.(Suponiendo que tu formula de área es correcta)

```
area=Math.sqrt(Math.abs(p*(p-(ladoA_B))*(p-(ladoB_C))*(p-(ladoC_A))));
```

> Y tenes mal los paracentesis en la fórmula de los lados, te doy un ejemplo de como va con el ladoA_B;

```
ladoA_B=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((puntoBx-puntoAx), 2)+Math.pow((puntoBy-puntoAy), 2));
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo,no soluciona mi problema, y es que dándole esos valores, debería salir en perímetro 16.70

Answer (score 1):

La formula que ingresaste para hallar la distancia entre dos vértices esta mal
lo que tu ingresaste es:

[image: Corregir]

Así debería ser:

[image: Así es]

Con la formula correcta los lados me salen:

6.32455532034

5.38516480713

5

Y en la parte para hallar el área por la formula de Herón no se divide entre 3 el perímetro sino entre dos, al dividir el perímetro entre 3 con los datos que ingresaste te da 16.66666..., y aplicando la formula que ingresaste para hallar el área seria así:

[image: raíz negativa]

en la parte 16 - 27 te da -10.3333333333

esto hace que todo dentro de la raíz sea negativo y al calcular la raíz cuadrada con Math.sqrt() te devuelve NaN.

Otra cosa creo que según los lados deberías comprobar si el triangulo existe o no.